# How to change Outlook 2003 Contacts default "File as" category?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, contacts

Is there a way to change the default "File as" category for the contacts in Outlook 2003? By default, only the First, Last name is displayed but I'd like to set by default:

> *First, Last name (Society)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help: [OL2002: How to Change the File As Field for All Contacts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291144):

> This article describes how to use a custom Outlook form and Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript) to programmatically change the File As field for a large number of existing contacts.